# AWS Java SDK: Specifying KMS Key Id For EBS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kms

In the AWS Java SDK 1.10.69, I can launch an instance and specify EBS volume mappings for the instance:

```
    RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest();

    String userDataString = Base64.encodeBase64String(userData.toString().getBytes());

    runInstancesRequest
            .withImageId(machineImageId)
            .withInstanceType(instanceType.toString())
            .withMinCount(minCount)
            .withMaxCount(maxCount)
            .withKeyName(sshKeyName)
            .withSecurityGroupIds(securityGroupIds)
            .withSubnetId(subnetId)
            .withUserData(userDataString)
            .setEbsOptimized(true);


    final EbsBlockDevice ebsBlockDevice = new EbsBlockDevice();
    ebsBlockDevice.setDeleteOnTermination(true);
    ebsBlockDevice.setVolumeType(VolumeType.Gp2);
    ebsBlockDevice.setVolumeSize(256);
    ebsBlockDevice.setEncrypted(true);

    final BlockDeviceMapping mapping = new BlockDeviceMapping();
    mapping.setDeviceName("/dev/sdb");
    mapping.setEbs(ebsBlockDevice);
```

It seems that currently I can only enable / disable encryption on the volume, and not specify which KMS Customer Master Key to use for the volume.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: See my other answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47602790/7692970) for the much easier solution now available

To specify a Customer Master Key (CMK) for an EBS volume for an instance, you have to combine the `RunInstancesRequest` with a `CreateVolumeRequest` and an `AttachVolumeRequest`. Otherwise, if you just specify `true` for encryption on the `EbsBlockDevice` it will use the default CMK.

First create the instance(s), without specifying the EBS volumes in the block device mapping of the `RunInstancesRequest`, then separately [create the volumes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2.html#createVolume-com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.CreateVolumeRequest-), then [attach them](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2.html#attachVolume-com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AttachVolumeRequest-).

`CreateVolumeRequest` has `withKmsKeyId()`/`setKmsKeyId()` options.

For example, updating your code might look like:

```
RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest();

String userDataString = Base64.encodeBase64String(userData.toString().getBytes());

runInstancesRequest
        .withImageId(machineImageId)
        .withInstanceType(instanceType.toString())
        .withMinCount(minCount)
        .withMaxCount(maxCount)
        .withKeyName(sshKeyName)
        .withSecurityGroupIds(securityGroupIds)
        .withSubnetId(subnetId)
        .withUserData(userDataString)
        .setEbsOptimized(true);
RunInstancesResult runInstancesResult = ec2Client.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);

for (Instance instance : runInstancesResult.getReservation()) {
    CreateVolumeRequest volumeRequest = new CreateVolumeRequest()
            .withAvailabilityZone(instance.getPlacement().getAvailabilityZone())
            .withKmsKeyId(/* CMK id or alias/yourkeyaliashere */)
            .withEncrypted(true)
            .withSize(256)
            .withVolumeType(VolumeType.Gp2);
    CreateVolumeResult volumeResult = ec2Client.createVolume(volumeRequest);
    AttachVolumeRequest attachRequest = new AttachVolumeRequest()
            .withDevice("/dev/sdb")
            .withInstanceId(instance.getInstanceId())
            .withVolumeId(volumeResult.getVolume().getVolumeId());
    ec2Client.attachVolume(attachRequest);
}
```

Note: If you make use of the block device mapping in instance metadata, it does not get updated when you attach a volume to a running instance. To bring it up to date, you can stop/start the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Good news! AWS has just added the ability to specify CMK key ids in the block device mapping when launching instances.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/EbsBlockDevice.html#setKmsKeyId-java.lang.String-

This was added to the AWS Java SDK in version  1.11.237.

Therefore in your original code you now just add

```
ebsBlockDevice.setKmsKeyId(keyId);
```

where keyId can be a CMK alias (in the form `alias/<alias name>`), key id (looks like `1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab`) or full CMK ARN (`arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:111122223333:key/1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab`).